# Post-process bazel test command generated reports

Tags: bazel

I'm using Bazel on my CI server for building and testing my C++ library, but I can't retrieve generated reports/logs files.

I wonder if there is a way to refer to those generated files for a further use inside a `genrule` which can permit me to post-process files (generate HTML...) ?

**bazel execution :**

```sh
$ bazel test //unit:tests
INFO: Analyzed 2 targets (21 packages loaded, 400 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 test targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 29,326s, Critical Path: 6,86s
INFO: 22 processes: 22 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 29 total actions
//unit:tests_a                                                 PASSED in 0.7s
//unit:tests_b                                                 PASSED in 0.7s

Executed 2 out of 2 tests: 2 tests pass.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 29 total actions
```

**generated reports :**

```sh
$ find bazel-out/ -name '*.xml' -or -name '*.log'
bazel-out//darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/unit/tests_a/test.log
bazel-out//darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/unit/tests_a/test.xml
bazel-out//darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/unit/tests_b/test.log
bazel-out//darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/unit/tests_b/test.xml
```

**WORKSPACE :**

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "gtest",
    url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.zip",
    sha256 = "94c634d499558a76fa649edb13721dce6e98fb1e7018dfaeba3cd7a083945e91",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.10.0",
)
```

**unit/BUILD :**

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_test")
test_suite(name = "tests", tests = glob(["tests_*"]))
cc_test(name = "tests_a", srcs = ["ut.cc"], deps = ["@gtest//:gtest_main"])
cc_test(name = "tests_b", srcs = ["ut.cc"], deps = ["@gtest//:gtest_main"])
```

**unit/ut.cc :**

```cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
TEST(HelloTest, GetGreet) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can save report gen by bazel test via PATH indicated by the env var: TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR。bazel test will save your report in bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs////<test_binary_targrt>/test.outputs/outputs.zip
check this out:https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html#initial-conditions